# 500 (Internal Server Error) and Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to create a website based on guides. When it came to updating the basket through the buttons (decrease and increase), then trying to click on them, errors are issued: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0, which refers to

```
.then((data) => {
        location.reload()
    });
```

cart.js:24 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_item/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
which refers to

```
fetch(url, {
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        },
```

and i have error in console pycharm line 104, in updateItem
productId = data['productId']
KeyError: 'productId'

code cart.js:

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var productId = this.dataset.stuff
        var action = this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId:', productId, 'Action:', action)

        console.log('USER:', user)
        if (user == 'AnonymousUser') {
            console.log('User is not authenticated')

        } else {
            updateUserOrder(productId, action)
        }

    })
}

function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
    console.log('User is authenticated, sending data...')

        var url = '/update_item/'

        fetch(url, {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action})
        })
        .then((response) => {
           return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            location.reload()
        });
}
```

views.py

```
def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print('Action:', action)
    print('Product:', productId)

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Stuff.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)

    orderItem.save()

    if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
        orderItem.delete()

    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is your Python version?
From `Python v3.0`, `json.loads()` will only accept unicode string.

Maybe the problem is that you have to decode request.body first :

```
data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```

If this is not the problem try to check what you are receiving. Because the `"<"` character looks like html or xml. For example, change your function to:

```
def updateItem(request):
 data = json.loads(request.body)
 return HttpResponse(data)
```

Comment: i have python 3.8. I tried to do what you wrote, but I get exactly the same errors

Comment: I think you're receiving HTML (or XML) back from the server, and not json. Check the "Network" tab in Chrome dev tools to see contents of the server's response. Or print what you are receiving:

    def updateItem(request):
     data = json.loads(request.body)
     return HttpResponse(data)

Comment: what exactly should I see there?

Comment: Request headers:
Content-Type: application/json

response headers:
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8